# Why do these two methods return different things?

Tags: c, stdin, printf, fgetc

So...I was trying to make my own simple keylogger and this works for things typed at the shell, but if I double click the executable file it just puts a lot of these in the file: `ÿ`

I understand that as of now if I type a <kbd>j</kbd> it will end; this is for debugging:

---

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(void)
{ 
FILE *fp = fopen("log", "w");
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        int x=0;
        while (x==0)
        {
            char input=fgetc(stdin);
            if (input==*"j")
                x=1;
            else
            {
              fprintf(fp, "%c\n",input);
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because there's no input stream when you double click, or it's empty straight away. In those conditions, `fgetc` will return `EOF` continously. I can't say that for sure but it explains the symptoms you're seeing.

You need to compare `input` against `EOF` to see if the end of the stream has been found because, in that circumstance, you'll never get the chance to input `j`. Try changing:

```
if (input==*"j")
```

to:

```
if ((input == 'j') || (input == EOF))
```

(you'll noticed I've changed the rather ... unusual `*"j"` xonstruct to the simpler `'j'` as well).

The return value from `fgetc` should also be an `int` since it has to represent every possible character *plus* `EOF`.

Comment: So...this did fix it but my question is generally why is the input stream empty or nonexistent?  Why does it continually return EOF?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> char input=fgetc(stdin);
> ```

Please note that `fgetc()` requires an `int` (well, something larger than a `char` -- `int` is customary) for its return value: `EOF` is a possible return value in addition to any of the values that `char` might take.

> ```
> if (input==*"j")
> ```

Yikes, this is *awkward*. :) Character comparison (if that were okay in this case) would look like:

```
if (input == 'j')
```

Knowing the difference between a `''` character and `""` string are vital to being a good [c](/questions/tagged/c) programmer. It might feel stilted after the free-form `'string'` `"string"` and `"""string"""` sorts of behaviors from other scripting languages, but it's the way it is.

Typically, these sorts of programs are written with a different layout:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    /* do something with c */
}
```

Putting an assignment *and* test in the condition of a `while` might feel weird at first, but it is idiomatic. (And I've sorely missed this behavior in languages that forbid it.)

Comment: actually...*"j" works because "j" is a string (the location of the first character) and since *"j" evaluates to the value at that location it would be the char j

Comment: @Jack, `*"jehova's witness"` would work as well but would be equally strange. Any decent compiler would probably optimise that down to the same thing but it won't stop the programmers who inherit your code from questioning your sanity :-)